# Excel: Validate a decimal value in a cell making sure it contains one of four conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a sheet  that people enter to track effort time. They need to enter in 15 minute increments therefor, the cell can only **end** in:
.00 or .25 or .50 or .75 as an acceptable entry. The number before the decimal can be anything.

How can we validate in the cell as they do entry that the entered value is acceptable.  Example 1.26 is not valid.

Comment: so, do you know how to do data validation, and you just want the formula?

Comment: Note the two different approaches in the answers.  datatoo's answer validates whether the value has been entered according to the rules (what you asked for).  Hannu's answer just goes ahead and corrects any improper entries, eliminating the additional step of correcting the bad entries.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes I see two different approaches. I do not want to have it auto correct, I want the user to fill in correctly. I want this validation to happen in that field as they enter.  I will try to add those conditions in a formula as under data validation and report back if this works or if I need more help.

Answer (score 1):

If the cell you are checking is in A2

```
=IF(MOD(A2,0.25)>0,"invalid","ok")
```

Comment: Correction to above...    This is working for what I wanted. I am checking another cell (A3) to make sure a date is entered first. Once a date is entered they will need to enter a time value with the conditions mentioned before.   One more thing I would like to add is to make sure that  they cannot enter a value of 0.00 for time.  Here is the formula I am using but cannot seem to get the if statement to correctly add checking for a 0.00 entry.  I want a 0.00 entry to = invalid. 
     
=IF(A3="","ok",IF(H3="","invalid",IF(MOD(H3,0.25)>0,"invalid","ok")))

Comment: Chris you can check for blanks or 0 with    
      =IF(OR(H3="",H3=0,MOD(H3,0.25)>0),"invalid","ok")

Comment: PERFECT!  Love this site! I Never knew how to nest OR in an IF statement. I was always IF~ing it to death!   Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives, for automatic adjustment:

Strip off to next lower even 1/4th
`=A1-MOD(A1,1/4)`

Round to closest even 1/4th
`=INT(A1*4+0.5)/4`

*(user entry in A1)*